# Why is this JSON returning as "Invalid JSON primitive"?

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization, deserialization

The following JSON is not deserializing.  It's obviously because the DECIMALS in the saves JSON.  How do I fix this?

**This initial JSON comes from the server and IS VALID:**

```
    {
    "AppropriationAmount": 25000000, 
    "AppropriationHours": 56300, 
    "ArrThreshold": 11, 
    "ClientKey": 24, 
    "Description": 'Find and incarcerate the escaped prisoner', 
    "DirectHours": 50000, 
    "EndDate": '3/31/2011', 
    "EngineeringHours": 4000, 
    "IndirectHours": 2000, 
    "Key": 1589, 
    "Number": '0', 
    "OtherHours": 300, 
    "ProductivityCurveType": 'BurnedEarned', 
    "ProjectManager": 'Doctor Who', 
    "ProjectName": 'Prisoner ZERO', 
    "StartDate": '5/1/2010' 
    }
```

**This subsequent JSON sent to the server FAILS:**
Once the user edits the form, the data is serialized client-side and sent BACK...where it (then) fails upon attempting to de-serialize the JSON.

```
    {
    "AppropriationAmount": 56300.00, 
    "AppropriationHours": 25000000.00, 
    "ArrThreshold": 11.00, 
    "ClientKey": , 
    "Description": 'Find and incarcerate the escaped prisoner', 
    "DirectHours": 50000.00, 
    "EndDate": '3/31/2011', 
    "EngineeringHours": 4000.00, 
    "IndirectHours": 2000.00, 
    "Key": 1589, 
    "Number": '0', 
    "OtherHours": 300.00, 
    "ProductivityCurveType": 'BurnedEarned', 
    "ProjectManager": 'Doctor Who', 
    "ProjectName": 'Prisoner ZERO', 
    "StartDate": '5/1/2010' 
    }
```

**This code throws the Error:**

```
    try
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.JSON))
        {
            serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dialog = serializer.Deserialize<ProjectDecorator>(this.JSON);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // The message shows here
    }
```

**The Error thrown looks like:**

```
{"Invalid JSON primitive: ."}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not only does `ClientKey` have no value, but you're risking JSON validness by not putting keys and values inside double quotations marks (`""`).

Your keys are OK, but `string` values must be surrounded by double quotes. Take a look at [JSON](http://www.json.org/) website to see what's allowed and what's not.

Answer (score 11):

"ClientKey": ,  has no value

http://www.jsonlint.com/