# MVC3 Complex JSON List Binding

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Having issues getting ASP.NET MVC3 to bind my complex JSON object that contains a list.

Here's the structure I have for my objects.

```
public class PageModel
{
    public PageModel() { }
    public CustomObject1 CustomObject { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CustomObject2> Objects { get; set; }

}

public class CustomObject1
{
    public CustomObject1() { }
    [Required]
    public int CustomId1 { get; set; }
    public string CustomName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomObject2
{
    public CustomObject2() { }
    [Required]
    public int Custom2Id { get; set; }
    public CustomObject3 SubItem { get; set; }
    public int SubItemId { get; set; }
}
```

You can assume `CustomObject3` is of similar structure - no need to duplicate yet another made up class, so I figure you can use your imagination :)

Here's the Javascript/Jquery that makes the POST call (assume all the JS leading up to this provides the correct data):

```
//$obj1 has all data for the first object
var firstObj = { };
firstObj.CustomId1 = $obj1.Id;
firstObj.CustomName = $obj1.Name;

var i = 0;

//$objects is an array with all the data
$.each($objects, function() {
    objsArray[i] = {
    Custom2Id: $(this).Id,
    SubItemId: $(this).itemId
    };

    ++i;
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Action/Method',
    data: { CustomObject: firstObj, Objects: objsArray },
    //Success/error handlers here
});
```

And finally (I know, quite some code) here's an overview of the method I have:

```
public class ActionController : Controller {
    public JsonResult Method(PageModel model) {
        //Gets here - model.CustomObject is filled correctly, and model.Objects has a correct count of whatever data I passed to the method - but all of the properties are empty!
    }
}
```

As I said, the first object is filled and all of the data is there when I debug and step through. If I pass two objects in the `Objects` array in the JSON object, I see a `Count` of 2 in the controller, but `Custom2Id` and `SubItemId` are empty.  What gives?

When I specify a `contentType` of `'application/json'` in my `$.ajax` call, MVC complains about the data being passed. Also tried splitting the `model` parameter in the MVC method into two separate parameters, but it does not help.

Any help is greatly appreciated - this one has me stumped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the solution to this particular issue is a combination of two or more solutions found elsewhere on SO (one of them possibly being Jakub's answer revolving around the use of a generic collection type - `IEnumerable` - as opposed to a more concrete one - `List`).

First, the server side code need not be changed - all is well on that front. All of the changes that need to be made are client side, and specifically how jQuery and your Javascript send the data to said server.

Here's the old Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Action/Method',
    data: { CustomObject: firstObj, Objects: objsArray },
    //Success/error handlers here
});
```

First issue here is that the Javascript is not informing the server at `'/Action/Method'` what exactly you're sending (is it binary, is it a mix of parameters, or is it JSON?) so adding a `contentType: 'application/json'` line will serve that purpose. When you do this, the server then knows that it must decode JSON...

But as it would stand now, the decoding would fail with an exception being thrown ("`Invalid JSON primitive`") before the code even enters your method (MVC handles the decoding and binding then). In the AJAX call above, I was building a new JSON object in the `$.ajax` options, but the JSON being sent wouldn't pass a JSON validator (James Kyburz mentions a great JSON validator: [JSONLint Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5586601/324527)). Instead, create the JSON object before the `$.ajax` call, and stringify the object so it's in a proper JSON format. Altogether, here's what the AJAX call should look like:

```
var dataObj = { CustomObject: firstObj, Objects: objsArray };

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Action/Method',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
    //Success/error handlers here
});
```

Comment: After hours seeking for a fully functional code, this solved my problem! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Change `public IEnumerable<CustomObject2> Objects { get; set; }` to `List<CustomObject2>`

Model binder doesn't know how to create an instance of `IEnumerable` interface, it needs something more concrete.

You also need to change this:

`data: { CustomObject: firstObj, Objects: objsArray }`

into

`data: { model: { CustomObject: firstObj, Objects: objsArray } }`

The `model` part matches the name of the parameter in your action.

Comment: I have played around with this - `IEnumerable`, `IList`, `List` all produce the same results - a list with the correct number of objects that have no values.

Comment: I disagree with your second part - while it may help in certain instances, MVC3 is smart enough to discern that the data I'm passing to it belongs to my `model` parameter. The working solution I described above does not specify the extra object layer to appease MVC - it's able to discern what I'm doing.